# Angular 7 shared service for siblings component to get data from other sibling

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-services

In my Angular 7 app I have two sibling componentns... configurator component and custom stepper component. In configurator component I have some functions that get data from my API and calculate some values... I want to show the calculated value in custom stepper component.

I have created a service called price-weight service but am unsure which code to move where and how to get the values from that service in the custom stepper component.

**configurator.component.ts has this code:**

```
constructor(
        public dialog: MatDialog,
        private httpClient: HttpClient,
        private _snackBar: MatSnackBar,
        public priceWeight: PriceWeightService,
    ) { }

ngOnInit() {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Auth-token': 'somerandomstring',
            })
        };
    
        this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}`, httpOptions).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.parseData(data);
                console.log('Izbrana konfig.:', this.selected);
                this.getTotalWeight();
                this.getTotalPrice();
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error', error);
            }
        );
    
        // this.getData();
        this.openDialog();
    }
    
    parseData(data: any) {
        console.log(data);
        this.data = data;
    
        let i = 0;
    
        for (const step of data.steps) {
            if (step.subcategory.length === 0) {
                this.selected[i] = {
                    ident: step.ident,
                    name: step.name,
                    optionIdent: step.options[0].ident,
                    optionName: step.options[0].name,
                    optionPrice: step.options[0].price,
                    optionWeight: step.options[0].weight,
                    categoryType: step.category_type,
                };
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    
    findElement(item) {
        return Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.optionIdent === item.ident).length > 0;
    }
    
    setOptionSelected(item, step) {
    
        if (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === step.ident).length > 0) {
    
            const selectedKey = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === step.ident);
            this.selected[selectedKey] = {'ident': step.ident, 'name': step.name, 'optionIdent': item.ident, 'optionName' : item.name, 'optionPrice' : item.price, 'optionWeight' : item.weight, 'categoryType' : step.category_type};
        } else {
    
            const totalLength = Object.keys(this.selected).length;
            this.selected[totalLength] = {'ident' : step.ident, 'name': step.name, 'optionIdent' : item.ident, 'optionName' : item.name, 'optionPrice' : item.price, 'optionWeight' : item.weight, 'categoryType' : step.category_type};
        }
        this.getTotalWeight();
        this.getTotalPrice();
    }
    
    setOptionSubCatSelected(item, step, subcategory) {
    
        if (step.category_type === 1 && (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === subcategory.ident && e.optionIdent === item.ident).length > 0 ) ) {

            const index: number = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === subcategory.ident && x.optionIdent === item.ident);
            if (index !== -1) {
                this.selected.splice(index, 1);
            }
        } else {
    
            if (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === subcategory.ident).length > 0) {
    
                const selectedKey = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === subcategory.ident);
                this.selected[selectedKey] = {
                    'ident': subcategory.ident,
                    'name': subcategory.name,
                    'optionIdent': item.ident,
                    'optionName' : item.name,
                    'optionPrice' : item.price,
                    'optionWeight' : item.weight,
                    'categoryType' : subcategory.category_type
                };
            } else {
                const totalLength = Object.values(this.selected).length;
                this.selected[totalLength] = {
                    'ident' : subcategory.ident,
                    'name': subcategory.name,
                    'optionIdent' : item.ident,
                    'optionName' : item.name,
                    'optionPrice' : item.price,
                    'optionWeight' : item.weight,
                    'categoryType' : subcategory.category_type
                };
            }
        }
        this.getTotalWeight();
        this.getTotalPrice();
    }
    
    setCheckSelected(item, step, subcategory) {
    
        if (step.category_type === 1 && (Object.values(this.selected).filter(e => e.ident === subcategory.ident && e.optionIdent === item.ident).length > 0 ) ) {
    
            const index: number = Object.values(this.selected).findIndex(x => x.ident === subcategory.ident && x.optionIdent === item.ident);
            if (index !== -1) {
                this.selected.splice(index, 1);
            }
    
        } else {
            const totalLength = Object.keys(this.selected).length;
            this.selected[totalLength] = {
                'ident' : subcategory.ident,
                'name': subcategory.name,
                'optionIdent' : item.ident,
                'optionName' : item.name,
                'optionPrice' : item.price,
                'optionWeight' : item.weight,
                'categoryType' : subcategory.category_type
            };
        }
        this.getTotalWeight();
        this.getTotalPrice();
    }
    
    getTotalPrice() {
        let totalPrice = 0;
        console.log('Price start:', totalPrice);
        for (const item of this.selected) {
            if (item.optionPrice) {
                totalPrice += Number(item.optionPrice);
                console.log('Price now:', totalPrice);
            }
        }
        console.log('Total price:', totalPrice);
        return totalPrice;
    }
    
    getTotalWeight() {
        let totalWeight = 0;
        console.log('Weight start:', totalWeight);
        for (const item of this.selected) {
            if (item.optionWeight) {
                totalWeight += Number(item.optionWeight);
                console.log('Weight now:', totalWeight);
            }
        }
        console.log('Total weight:', totalWeight);
        return totalWeight;
    }
```

Code in `custom-stepper.component.ts is this:`

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkStepper } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';

import { PriceWeightService } from '../_services/price-weight.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-stepper',
  templateUrl: './custom-stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-stepper.component.scss'],
    providers: [{provide: CdkStepper, useExisting: CustomStepperComponent}],
})

export class CustomStepperComponent extends CdkStepper {

    constructor(
        public priceWeight: PriceWeightService
    ){}

    onClick(index: number): void {
      this.selectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

and this is the html of custom-steppr how I wan't to show the values:

```
  <footer>
    <mat-toolbar>
      <h2>Step {{selectedIndex + 1}}/{{_steps.length}}</h2>
      <span class="fill-space"></span>
      <p class="mat-small"><strong>Total weight:</strong> {{ totalWeight | number: '1.2':'sl' }} KG</p>
      <span class="fill-space"></span>
      <p class="mat-small"><strong>Total price:</strong> {{ totalPrice | currency: 'EUR':'symbol':'4.2-2':'sl' }}</p>
      <span class="fill-space"></span>
      <button [ngClass]="selectedIndex > 0 ? 'noBtn': ''" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="naslednji-korak" [disabled]="(selectedIndex + 1)>_steps.length" cdkStepperNext>Begin configuration</button>
      <button [ngClass]="selectedIndex == 0 ? 'noBtn': ''" mat-raised-button color="secondary" class="naslednji-korak" [disabled]="selectedIndex == 0" cdkStepperPrevious>Previous step</button>
      <button [ngClass]="selectedIndex == 0 ? 'noBtn': ''" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="naslednji-korak" [disabled]="(selectedIndex + 1)==_steps.length" cdkStepperNext>Next step</button>
      <button [ngClass]="(selectedIndex + 1)<_steps.length ? 'noBtn': ''" mat-raised-button color="primary" class="naslednji-korak" [disabled]="(selectedIndex + 1)<_steps.length" (click)="reset()">Submit order</button>
    </mat-toolbar>
  </footer>
```

I have added the service with this code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PriceWeightService {
  weight = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create properties in the service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PriceWeightService {
  weight = 0;
}
```

Inject the service into **both components**

```js
constructor(private priceWeight: PriceWeightService){}
```

Set a property on the service **from you configurator component** like this

```js
this.priceWeight.weight = this.getTotalWeight();
```

**Services are singleton, so this will update that property for any other components that have injected the service.**

To use the service property **in your stepper component**, either make the service public, or create a getter.

```js
constructor(public priceWeight: PriceWeightService){}
```

```html
<p>{{priceWeight.weight}}</p>
```

or

```js
constructor(private priceWeight: PriceWeightService){}

get weight(){
  return this.priceWeight.weight;
}
```

```html
<p>{{weight}}</p>
```

---

**The specific code you need**

**service**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PriceWeightService {
  price = 0;
  weight = 0;
}
```

**configurator.component.ts**

```js
this.httpClient.get(`${environment.apiUrl}`, httpOptions).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                this.parseData(data);
                console.log('Izbrana konfig.:', this.selected);
                this.priceWeightService.weight = this.getTotalWeight();
                this.priceWeightService.price = this.getTotalPrice();
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('Error', error);
            }
        );
```

**custom-stepper.component.ts**

```js
  constructor(private priceWeight: PriceWeightService){}

  get totalWeight(){
    return this.priceWeight.weight;
  }

  get totalPrice(){
    return this.priceWeight.price;
  }
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I am having some issues with implementing this service. When I include the service in my custom-stepper.component.ts I get htis error: @Output selectionChange not initialized in 'CustomStepperComponent'. 
I have updated the code in my post so you can take a look at it. ALso how does weight = 0 in service help me get the calculated weight in the stepper component?

Comment: I edited my answer to be more clear. That error has nothing to do with the service, nor any code that you've shown in your question. Perhaps this is from extending `CdkStepper`? Since you've extended that class, you may need to inject the same services from that class and call `super()`.

Comment: I'm not sure in which file to add this this.priceWeight.weight = this.getTotalWeight(); code? does it belon in the service file or inside ngOninit in the configurator.ts file?

Comment: Also is there something I should call in the super()? since I'm getting an error saying:  Expected 2-4 arguments, but got 0.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the specific code you need. Yes `super()` is a call to the parent class' constructor so you need to pass all the parameters listed in that constructor.

Comment: What exactly would these parameters be? This is how my constructor looks now: constructor(
        private priceWeight: PriceWeightService,
    ) {
        super(undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined);
    }

Comment: You need to look at the `CdkStepper` constructor.